# Turn links in wicket panels to hyperlinks

Tags: wicket

I'm trying to find a way to automatically convert links in a panel to hyper-links. So for example a user input is:

`"And here you can find my awesome example: http://example.com"`

Is it possible in wicket to add an anchor element to each "http://..." text, so the above example would output

`"And here you can find my awesome example: <a href="http://example.com">http://example.com</a>"`

instead?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use Wicket's built in [SmartLinkLabel](http://wicket.apache.org/apidocs/1.4/org/apache/wicket/extensions/markup/html/basic/SmartLinkLabel.html).

From the Javadoc:

> If you have email addresses or web URLs in the data that you are displaying, then you can automatically display those pieces of data as hyperlinks, you will not have to take any action to convert that data.

Answer (score 3):

One way to do this is to extend [Label](http://wicket.apache.org/apidocs/1.4/org/apache/wicket/markup/html/basic/Label.html) and override onComponentTagBody

Something like:

```
public class AnchorizeLabel extends Label {

    public AnchorizeLabel(String id, String body) {
        super(id, body);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onComponentTagBody(MarkupStream stream, ComponentTag tag) {
        String newBody = createAnchors(getDefaultModelObjectAsString());
        replaceComponentTagBody(stream, tag, newBody);
    }

    private String createAnchors(String body) { 
        // regex magic to create links
    }
}
```

You can also accomplish this with a custom [IModel](http://wicket.apache.org/apidocs/1.4/org/apache/wicket/model/IModel.html) or [IConverter](http://wicket.apache.org/apidocs/1.4/org/apache/wicket/util/convert/IConverter.html) but I prefer the Label approach.